# display data from database mySQL in a drop down list in a Wordpress page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, wordpress

I'm a beginner in PHP and I want to display data from a database MySQL, in a drop down list in a page of Wordpress. I used this code:

```
<tr>
<td> Owner </td>
<td>
<select name="owner">
<?php 
// $connection = mysql_connect(localhost, root, );
$connection = mysql_connect(localhost, root, );

$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Nom FROM `herboristes`");

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

?>
</select>
<option value="owner1"><?php echo $row['Nom']; ?></option>
</td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that I get an empty dropdown list as you see in the image below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQvJx.png)

Please, any suggestions.
Thank you!

Comment: You cannot mix MySQL APIs. Use mysqli_ throughout

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

?>
</select>
<option value="owner1"><?php echo $row['Nom']; ?></option>
</td>
</tr>
```

maybe missing?

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tied this but it didn't work

<tr>
  <td> Owner </td>
  <td>
    <select name="owner">
    <?php 

    $connection = mysqli_connect(localhost, root, );  //mysqli here
mysqli_select_db($connection,somapam_bd);
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Nom FROM `herboristes`");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){   //mysqli here
       echo '<option value="owner1">'. $row["Nom"] .'</option>';  //echo your options here
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you want to use? mysql?mysqli? I can't know .. *But you shouldn't use `mysql_` you can take a look at* [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) ..  So we'll say you will use `mysqli`

```
<tr>
  <td> Owner </td>
  <td>
    <select name="owner">
    <?php 
    // $connection = mysql_connect(localhost, root, );
    $connection = mysqli_connect(localhost, root, );  //mysqli here

    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Nom FROM `herboristes`");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){   //mysqli here
       echo '<option value="owner1">'. $row["Nom"] .'</option>';  //echo your options here
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Well, it's true, you can't know, but the insecure and deprecated alternative certainly seems less attractive

Comment: I tied this but it didn't work

<tr>
  <td> Owner </td>
  <td>
    <select name="owner">
    <?php 

    $connection = mysqli_connect(localhost, root, );  //mysqli here
mysqli_select_db($connection,somapam_bd);
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Nom FROM `herboristes`");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){   //mysqli here
       echo '<option value="owner1">'. $row["Nom"] .'</option>';  //echo your options here
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root");
```

**or**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of writing database connection in wordpress pages
instead we can use

```
    <tr>
    <td> Owner </td>
    <td>
    <select name="owner">
<?php 
        global $wpdb;
        $entries = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Nom  FROM herboristes");
        foreach( $entries as $entry ) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo  $entry->Nom; ?>"><?php echo  $entry->Nom; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>

    </select>
```